# Is there any way we can make "cypress-axe" plugin to test accessibility issues within iframe?

Tags: automation, cypress, accessibility

I am currently automating testing Accessibility Issues using cypress. But our application is build under iframe, so when I try to run checkAlly() . Plugin is testing only outside part of iframe.

Following is the attached code for cypress-plugin.

```
function invokeAccessibility() {

  cy.injectAxe();
  cy.configureAxe({
    branding: {
      brand: String,
      application: String
    },
    reporter: 'option',
    //checks: [Object],
    //locale: Object
  });
  //4th argument - Allow fail, More info: https://github.com/avanslaars/cypress-axe


  cy.checkA11y(null, {
    includedImpacts: ['critical', 'serious']
    // enableIframe: true
  },
    terminalLog,
    true
  );

}
```

We call this function to check accessibility issue in particular Scenarios within iframe body. For ex:

```
cy.getFalloutIframe().within(() => {
    /* some responsivness action */ 
    invokeAccessibility();
  })
```

I expect that cypress-axe plugin should also give Issues within iframe.

Comment: why did you comment out enableIframe: true section? if you uncomment it, your code should work properly. By setting enableIframe: true, Cypress Axe will check for accessibility issues both within and outside of iframes.